# CSS Sprite Button With float:left... Not centering inside a table in Firefox

Tags: css, xhtml, css-float, sprite

Amazing...something I have gotten to work in IE and NOT Firefox!  Quite the turn of events, eh?

Anyway, here's the problem.  Check out the following page in both IE and Firefox:

http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html

I'm using this file to put together the button.

[image] (http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/composite__V153767378_.png)

Obviously this button is centered in only IE.. what gives?!
I'm using a span for the background that is under the text and another for the tip and then floating them together with float: left as you can see by viewing the source.

So, what can I do to get this span centered in Firefox?

Thanks in advance.. please let me know if there you have any questions about this that I can help answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `span.buttonLarge` contains two uncleared floated block-level elements, hence no centering. In order to fix this, you could apply `display: inline-block` and `margin: 0 auto` to it.

P.S. You don't have a `DOCTYPE` specified, that's why your current solution works in IE - it is rendering it in Quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: left;` from `.primaryLargeButtonSpan` and `.primaryLargeButtonEnd`

after that change `display: block;` to `display: inline;` from `.spriteButton span.button_label`
OR change it to `display: inline-block;` and then, set the `background` property to `url("./composite__V153767378_.png") no-repeat scroll left -76px transparent;`

You might notice some "defect" in the ending image though...